# vb sql command inserted but not data display in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, command

My question is my code has problem or not to insert into database. Why I cannot insert it?
I think the data has saved but it not show in database. Please help me see it, thank you.

```vb
    Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HTPdatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer (Username,Password,Name,IC,Address,Email,Carpark,topup)VALUES(@Username,@password,@Name,@IC,@address,@Email,@Carpark,@topup)"
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", UsernameTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", PasswordTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", DBNull.Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IC", DBNull.Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", DBNull.Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", DBNull.Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Carpark", DBNull.Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topup", DBNull.Value)
    MsgBox("Successfully register!Please remind customer to update own profile,Thank you !")
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: no but the database no any data saved after i click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code it looks ok but

Place

```
MsgBox("Successfully register!Please remind customer to update own profile,Thank you !")
```

below

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

because during cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() code may fail and exception may raise.

Comment: what is difference between (Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\limyj_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SDP assignment\SDP assignment\HTPdatabase.mdf";Integrated Security=True) and (Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HTPdatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"), could u tell me?

Comment: Difference is first one is attaching the database from the location you have given. Which may fail when project is run on another system. and second one is attaching the database from project location, which is recommended setting.

Comment: Why when i use first one, the data cannot save, second connection can save data? It suddenly cannot use the first one to save data. Last week i can use it but this week suddenly cannot use it. What problem about it?

Comment: Please check if you are redirected to same database for both else you might be having two databases or you might be getting some error during execution.